# how to remove square after 2 seconds

Tags: python, pygame

I have this code and I don't know how to make the red cube disappear after 2 seconds.

```py
import pygame
import sys
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()

a=0

#display
prozor = pygame.display.set_mode((800,800))
FPS = pygame.time.Clock()
FPS.tick(60)

#boje
green=pygame.Color(0 ,255 , 0)
red=pygame.Color(255, 0, 0)
yellow=pygame.Color(255, 255, 0)
blue=pygame.Color(0, 0, 255)
black=pygame.Color(0, 0, 0)
white=pygame.Color(255, 255, 255)


#class

class Cube:
    def update(self):
        self.cx, self.cy = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        self.square = pygame.Rect(self.cx, self.cy, 50, 50)

    def draw(self): 
        pygame.draw.rect(prozor, (255, 0, 0), self.square)

cube = Cube()
drawing_cube = False

#objekt
for j in range(16):
    for i in range(800):
            if i%50 == 0:
                pygame.draw.rect(prozor, green, ((0+i, a), (50, 50),),1)
    a=a+50


#gameloop
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            cube.update()
            drawing_cube = True
    if drawing_cube:
        cube.draw()
        pygame.display.flip()
    pygame.display.update()
```

Adding it to the draw class will just freeze the game and shut it.

```py
def draw(self): 
    pygame.draw.rect(prozor, red, self.square)
    time.sleep(3)
    pygame.draw.rect(prozor, black, self.square
```

I tried making another class called delete which would delete the cube after 3 seconds using the time module.

```py
def delete(self):
    time.sleep(3)
    pygame.draw.rect(prozor, black, self.square)
```

and added it here

```py
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            cube.update()
            drawing_cube = True
    if drawing_cube:
        cube.draw()
        pygame.display.flip()
        **cube.delete**
        pygame.display.flip()
    pygame.display.update()
```

but the cube is not disappearing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`pygame.time.get_ticks`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html) to measure the time in milliseconds. Calculate the time when the cube must disappear again and hide the cube if the current time is greater than the calculated time. You also need to clear the display (`prozor.fill(0)`) and redraw the scene in each frame:

```py
drawing_cube = False
hide_cube_time = 0

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(100)
    current_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            run = False

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            cube.update()
            drawing_cube = True
            hide_cube_time = current_time + 2000 # 2000 milliseconds == 2 sconds

    if current_time > hide_cube_time:
        drawing_cube = False

    prozor.fill(0)
    a=0
    for j in range(16):
        for i in range(800):
            if i%50 == 0:
                pygame.draw.rect(prozor, green, (0+i, a, 50, 50), 1)
        a=a+50
    if drawing_cube:
        cube.draw()
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
sys.exit()
```

Note, the typical PyGame application loop has to:

- limit the frames per second to limit CPU usage with [`pygame.time.Clock.tick`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock)
- handle the events by calling either [`pygame.event.pump()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump) or [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get).
- update the game states and positions of objects dependent on the input events and time (respectively frames)
- clear the entire display or draw the background
- draw the entire scene (`blit` all the objects)
- update the display by calling either [`pygame.display.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update) or [`pygame.display.flip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip)

Comment: Thank you, it works, just had to reset the a to 0.